# Transform Dataframe of two columns into sorted list

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe which is given below

```
year         title
2021         Title1234
2021         Title12
2021         Title123
2021         Title12345
2021         Title1
2020         Title2234
2020         Title22
2020         Title223
2020         Title22345
2021         Title2
```

I want to dump all the data under title column in a list in a sorted manner at two levels - first a year level and second length of the title, both in a descending order.

```
Title12345
Title1234
Title123
Title12
Title1
Title22345
Title2234
Title223
Title22
Title2
```

I have tried to transform dataframe by applying group by on year and collect_set on title and iterate over the dataframe and dump data into a map. Then iterated over of sorted key set and fetching lists from map and dump into a list.

I am looking for a more simple and straight forward method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most methods in [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html) return a column object. So the return value of [length](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#length(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) can be used as sorting criterion in `orderBy`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.orderBy($"year".desc, length($"title").desc).show()
```

returns the expected result.